# Order words by alphabet

Tags: c#

How would you order the following words by these alphabets?

```
string[] _words1 = {"road", "apple", "maple", "roam", "wind"};
string _alphabet1 = "irqjfomqwijapfpdpwe";
```

Where each order of the words is determined by the _alphabet1, but the trick is "road" should come after "roam" because "r" is similar, "o" is similar", "a" is similar, and "d" comes after "m" in the _alphabet1

Use built-in array .Sort() and its overload.

This question came up for an interview and I couldn't do it. The interviewer said the .Sort() overload should be used to simplify the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define your own class that extends `Comparer`. Basically, you define how two strings are sorted in relation to one another, using the modified "alphabet" you're using.

```
public class MyComparer : Comparer<string>
{
    private string _alphabet1 = "irqjfomqwijapfpdpwe";

    public override int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var minLength = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);

        for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
        {
            var stringXpos = _alphabet1.IndexOf(x[i]);
            var stringYpos = _alphabet1.IndexOf(y[i]);

            if (stringXpos < stringYpos)
                return -1;

            if (stringYpos < stringXpos)
                return 1;
        }

        return x.Length < y.Length ? -1 : (x.Length > y.Length) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Then just instantiate it when you call `Array.Sort`:

```
string[] _words1 = { "road", "apple", "maple", "roam", "wind" };

Array.Sort(_words1, new MyComparer());
```

Content of `_words1`, after sorting:

```
roam
road
maple
wind
apple
```

Comment: _alphabet1.IndexOf(x[0]); it should be probably i not 0 here. Other things look nice :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to correctly handle characters that are not part of `_alphabet1`. Although, perhaps it's not clear what that behavior should be.

Comment: The interviewer had all the alphabets listed and mixed. I just made up this alphabet order.

Comment: Certainly there must be a more efficient way to do this than to look up every letter in the alphabet for each comparison.